# Disassembling Code inside of a C++ program

Tags: linux, security, x86-64, disassembly

`objdump -D file.o` will output something like

```
  2b:   47                      rex.RXB
  2c:   43                      rex.XB
  2d:   43 3a 20                rex.XB cmp (%r8),%spl
```

In my program I have a pointer to the instruction and need to disassemble the first instruction found (not the whole file).  What would be the easiest way to do that?  For example

```
uint8_t * inst_ptr = memory_location
std::string human_readable = get_disassembly(instr_ptr)
```

human_readable = "43 3a 20 rex.XB cmp (%r8),%spl"

Is there linux headers/includes that do this already?

Ive been googling but havent found a good, straight forward solution.

Comment: No there is no Linux headers that have functions that do that but there are third party libraries like Zydis  https://doc.zydis.re/master/html/ that do what you want.